# \rowcolor makes the text disappear

Tags: tables, color, longtable, rowcolor

I use rowcolors{...} to color a table,  After that, some text from my column  disappear slightly .
Why is that, and what can I do to fix the error?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage {multirow}
    \usepackage{lipsum}% example text
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[left=1.27cm,right=1.27cm,top=1.27cm,bottom=1.27cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
    \usepackage{ltablex,array}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \usepackage{printlen}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{colortbl} 
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{here}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
    \def\PILOTE{Responsable Qualité}
    \def\logo{gladis.png}
    \def\Date{07/03/22}
    \def\CIBLE{}
    \def\CIBLE{}
    \def\CIBLE{}
    \def\CIBLE{}
    \definecolor{Mycolor1}{RGB}{179,238,255}
    \definecolor{Mycolor2}{RGB}{53,166,197}
    \definecolor{Mycolor3}{RGB}{75,172,198}
    \definecolor{Mycolor4}{RGB}{49,132,155}
    \definecolor{Mycolor5}{RGB}{146,205,220}
    \definecolor{LightCyan}{RGB}{218,238,243}
    
    \begin{document}
        % données  entree / sortie
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        \begin{longtable}{C{4.8cm} C{7.7cm} C{4.7cm}}
            
            \rowcolor{Mycolor3}  &&\\
            \rowcolor{Mycolor3}\textbf{Données d’entrée}& \textbf{Description des ACTIVITÉS} & \textbf{Données de sortie} \\
            \rowcolor{Mycolor3}  &&\\
            %1
            
        \textbf{    Législation , Exigences }&  \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{ Déterminer et mettre en oeuvre le Système}}  &\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{SMQ défini et appliqué}}\\
            \textbf{normatives et réglementaires}   &  \textbf{de Management de la Qualité (SMQ)} &\\
            \textbf{Exigences clients}  & &\\
            %2
            \rowcolor{LightCyan}
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Processus}} & \textbf{Surveiller les processus } &  \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{SMQ cohérent et fiable}}\\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
            &(application, cohérence, etc.)&\\
            %3
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Normes et réglements}}  & \textbf{Réaliser la veille documentaire, normative }   & \textbf{Veille documentaire et} \\
            & \textbf{et réglementaire} & \textbf{normative}\\
            %4
            \rowcolor{LightCyan}
            \textbf{Exigences réglementaires} &\multirow{4}{*}{\parbox{0.95\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{Maîtriser la documentation et la modification  de la documentation}}} &\textbf{Systéme documentaire }  \\ \rowcolor{LightCyan}
            \textbf{et normatives} &&\textbf{complet et à jour}\\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
                \textbf{Procédure documentaire}& & (procédures, rapports ,\\ \rowcolor{LightCyan}
                \textbf{Besoin en traçabilité} && enregistrements, etc.) \\
            %5
            \textbf{Besoin de compréhension }  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{0.95\linewidth} {\centering \textbf{Communiquer et sensibiliser sur la qualité}  (Réunions, échanges)}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Personnel sensibilisé}} \\
            \textbf{ et d’adhésion des} &&\\
            \textbf{collaborateurs }&&\\
            %6
            \rowcolor{LightCyan}
            \multirow{4}{*}{\parbox{0.95\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{Exigences clients Exigences normatives et réglementaires} }} & \textbf{Assurer la conformité du produit} &\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Produit conforme} }\\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
            &(Effectuer les contrôles à réception, assurer la   &\\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
            &conformité de l’étiquetage et de la notice     &\\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
            &d’utilisation, vérifier les marquages CE, etc.)    &\\
            %7
        \textbf{    Réclamations} & \multirow{3}{*}{{\parbox{1\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{ Gérer les non-conformités (NC)}\newline (Fiches de NC, analyse des causes, suivi des NC)}}} &\multirow{3}{*}{ {\parbox{1\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{Base de données des NC,analyse de causes, CAPA }}}} \\
            \textbf{Procédure de gestion des }  &&\\
            \textbf{NC} &&\\
            %8
            \rowcolor{LightCyan}
            \textbf{Recherche d’amélioration} & \multirow{3}{*}{{\parbox{1\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{ Piloter les audits internes et fournisseurs
            }\newline(Réaliser les audits, participer aux audits)}}} &\multirow{3}{*}{ {\parbox{1\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{Rapports d’audits} }}} \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
            \textbf{Programme d’audit}  &&\\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
            \textbf{Besoin d’audit} &&\\
                
            %9
        
            \textbf{Besoin d’amélioration} &  \multirow{7}{*}{{\parbox{0.9\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{ Organiser les revues \newline(processus et de  direction)}\newline (Mesurer et surveiller la performance des\newline processus et de l’organisme) }}}&  \multirow{7}{*}{{\parbox{1\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{Revues de direction  \newline et Compte-Rendus  \newline de revue de direction }}}}\\
             \textbf{Veille réglementaire}  &&\\
            \textbf{et normative} &&\\
            \textbf{Analyse de données et}  &&\\
            \textbf{ objectifs de la direction} &&\\
             \textbf{Modification interne}  &&\\
            \textbf{ importante de l’entreprise} &&\\
             %10
             \rowcolor{LightCyan}
             \multirow{3}{*}{ \textbf{NC, Matériovigilance }} & \textbf{Informer le fabricant, les autorités }  &\multirow{3}{*}{{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering \qquad\textbf{ CAPA \newline Signalement aux autorités}}}}\\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
             & \textbf{compétentes ou le client} (si produit déjà &\\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
             & distribué, fiche  de rappel produit)  &\\
            %11
            \multirow{7}{*}{{\parbox{0.7\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{Politique et objectifs qualité,\newline Rapports d’audits, Indicateurs \newline Exigences clients }}}}&\multirow{7}{*}{{\parbox{1\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{Superviser l’amélioration continue \newline Mettre en place des indicateurs}}}}&\textbf{Système qualité CAPA (} \\
            && \textbf{lié aux actions correctives}  \\
            && \textbf{et préventives)} \\
            &&\textbf{Indicateurs performants}\\
            &&\textbf{ Modification interne }\\
            &&\textbf{ importante (SMQ ou} \\
            && \textbf{personnel)}\\
            %12
            \rowcolor{LightCyan}
            \textbf{Retours d’informations}  &\multirow{4}{*}{{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\textbf{ Analyser les réclamations et répondre aux interrogations clients}}}}&\textbf{Registres des réclamations} \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
            \textbf{et réclamations}    && \textbf{, des NC, des rappels et} \\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
            \textbf{Interrogations clients} && \textbf{des retraits}\\\rowcolor{LightCyan}
            &&\\
            
        \end{longtable}
        
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{longtable} [width=\textwidth]` ? longtable has no key=value option handling, and no width setting.

Comment: ok thank you , i deleted it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table is unnecessary complicated. All `multirow`s are unnecessary, multiline text can be complete in one cell and not each line in own rows.

For example, first four rows in table body should be as follows (written as MWE: Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, cellspace, longtable, ltablex,
            makecell, multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\definecolor{Mycolor3}{RGB}{75,172,198}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{RGB}{218,238,243}

\begin{document}
    % données  entree / sortie
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{}>{\bfseries}C{5.4cm}C{7cm}C{5.4cm} @{}}
    \rowcolor{Mycolor3}  &  &\\
    \rowcolor{Mycolor3}
Données d’entrée
    & \textbf{Description des ACTIVITÉS} 
        & \textbf{Données de sortie} \\
    \rowcolor{Mycolor3}  &&\\
%1
Législation , Exigences normatives et réglementaires Exigences clients
    &   \textbf{Déterminer et mettre en oeuvre le Système de Management de la Qualité (SMQ)}
        &   \textbf{SMQ défini et appliqué}         \\
%2
    \rowcolor{LightCyan}
Processus 
    & \textbf{Surveiller les processus} 
      (application, cohérence, etc.)
        & \textbf{SMQ cohérent et fiable}           \\
%3
Normes et réglements et réglementaire
    & \textbf{Réaliser la veille documentaire, normative}
        & \textbf{Veille documentaire et normative} \\
%4
    \rowcolor{LightCyan}
Exigences réglementaires et normatives

Procédure documentaire

Besoin en traçabilité
    & \textbf{Maîtriser la documentation et la modification  de la documentation} (procédures, rapports, enregistrements, etc.)
        & \textbf{Systéme documentaire complet et à jour}  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Comparison above table code with your should give you a clue, how you need to rewrite your table, that it will works as you desire.

BTW, in your document table are almost all packages load twice. Why?

**Edit:**
In cells, where you like to force text in new line, you have three possibilities:

- use `\newline`, which force line break but next line is not perfectly centered
- terminate text before required line beak by `\par`,  which line make as perfectly centered paragraph
- insert empty line which consequence is the same as at use of the `\par` command.

Used `\newline` in above MWE is now replaced with `\par`.

**Addendum:**
A simpler and shorter table code is obtained by using of the `tabularray` package. With small reformatting of columns width and merging unnecessary rows, table become more compact and can be fir on one page:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\definecolor{Mycolor3}{RGB}{75,172,198}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{RGB}{218,238,243}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[p]
    \small
\begin{tblr}{colsep=4pt,
             colspec = {@{} *{3}{X[c]} @{}},
             row{1} = {rowsep=5pt, font=\bfseries, bg=Mycolor3},
             row{even} = {LightCyan},
             hline{Z} = {solid}
             }
Données d’entrée
    &   Description des ACTIVITÉS 
        &   Données de sortie                   \\
%1
Législation , Exigences normatives et réglementaires Exigences clients
    &   Déterminer et mettre en oeuvre le Système de Management de la Qualité (SMQ) 
        &   SMQ défini et appliqué              \\
%2
Processus
    &   Surveiller les processus
        (application, cohérence, etc.)
        &   SMQ cohérent et fiable              \\
%3
Normes et réglements et réglementaire
    &   Réaliser la veille documentaire, normative 
        &   Veille documentaire et normative    \\
%4
Exigences réglementaires et normatives\par
Procédure documentaire\par
Besoin en traçabilité
    &   Maîtriser la documentation et la modification  de la documentation (procédures, rapports, enregistrements, etc.)
        &   Systéme documentaire complet et à jour  \\
%5
Besoin de compréhension et d’adhésion des collaborateurs
    &   Communiquer et sensibiliser sur la qualité  (Réunions, échanges) 
        &   Personnel sensibilisé               \\
%6
Exigences clients Exigences normatives et réglementaires
    &   Assurer la conformité du produit Effectuer les contrôles à réception, assurer la d’utilisation, vérifier les marquages CE, etc.)
        &   Produit conforme conformité de l’étiquetage et de la notice                                  \\
%7
Réclamations\par
Procédure de gestion des NC
    &    Gérer les non-conformités (NC)\par 
        (Fiches de NC, analyse des causes, suivi des NC)
        &   Base de données des NC,analyse de causes, CAPA  \\
%8
Recherche d’amélioration\par
Programme d’audit\par
Besoin d’audit
    &   Piloter les audits internes et fournisseurs\par
        (Réaliser les audits, participer aux audits)
        &   Rapports d’audits                   \\
%   newpage
%9
Besoin d’amélioration\par
Veille réglementaire et normative\par
Analyse de données et objectifs de la direction\par
Modification interne importante de l’entreprise
    &   Organiser les revues\par
    (processus et de  direction)\par
    (Mesurer et surveiller la performance des\newline processus et de l’organisme)
        &   Revues de direction et Compte-Rendus de revue de direction                               \\
%10
NC, Matériovigilance
    &   Informer le fabricant, les autorités 
        &   CAPA \par 
            Signalement aux autorités
        compétentes ou le client distribué, fiche  de rappel produit
        (si produit déjà)                       \\
%11
Politique et objectifs qualité,\newline Rapports d’audits, Indicateurs\par
Exigences clients
    &   Superviser l’amélioration continue \newline Mettre en place des indicateurs 
        &   Système qualité CAPA\par
            (lié aux actions correctives et préventives)\par
             Indicateurs performants\par
            Modification interne importante (SMQ ou personnel)  \\
%12
Retours d’informations et réclamations\par
Interrogations clients
    &   Analyser les réclamations et répondre aux interrogations clients 
        &   Registres des réclamations, des NC, des rappels et des retraits    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i used multirow because i when i had some issue with centring teh texte on the cellule olso i coudn't use \newline in the cellule .
 i compilate your code and i had the some isue the table idsn't fit on the page .
concerning the packages it is because whatever I found a problem I seek I find the solution + the package so I still didn't check them.

Comment: @MASSAL, I show you in my MWE, that you are wrong. Do you compare my and your MWE? That my work correctly you can see from showed result. You only need to rewrite rest of rows as I do for first four in table body.

Comment: @MASSAL, see edited answer as well added addendum in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\definecolor{Mycolor3}{RGB}{75,172,198}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{RGB}{218,238,243}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\small
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{} *{3}{X[c]} @{}}[color-inside]
\RowStyle[bold,rowcolor=Mycolor3]{}
Données d’entrée
    &   Description des ACTIVITÉS 
        &   Données de sortie                   \\
\rowcolors{LightCyan}{}
%1
Législation , Exigences normatives et réglementaires Exigences clients
    &   Déterminer et mettre en oeuvre le Système de Management de la Qualité (SMQ) 
        &   SMQ défini et appliqué              \\
%2
Processus
    &   Surveiller les processus
        (application, cohérence, etc.)
        &   SMQ cohérent et fiable              \\
%3
Normes et réglements et réglementaire
    &   Réaliser la veille documentaire, normative 
        &   Veille documentaire et normative    \\
%4
Exigences réglementaires et normatives\par
Procédure documentaire\par
Besoin en traçabilité
    &   Maîtriser la documentation et la modification  de la documentation (procédures, rapports, enregistrements, etc.)
        &   Systéme documentaire complet et à jour  \\
%5
Besoin de compréhension et d’adhésion des collaborateurs
    &   Communiquer et sensibiliser sur la qualité  (Réunions, échanges) 
        &   Personnel sensibilisé               \\
%6
Exigences clients Exigences normatives et réglementaires
    &   Assurer la conformité du produit Effectuer les contrôles à réception, assurer la d’utilisation, vérifier les marquages CE, etc.)
        &   Produit conforme conformité de l’étiquetage et de la notice                                  \\
%7
Réclamations\par
Procédure de gestion des NC
    &    Gérer les non-conformités (NC)\par 
        (Fiches de NC, analyse des causes, suivi des NC)
        &   Base de données des NC,analyse de causes, CAPA  \\
%8
Recherche d’amélioration\par
Programme d’audit\par
Besoin d’audit
    &   Piloter les audits internes et fournisseurs\par
        (Réaliser les audits, participer aux audits)
        &   Rapports d’audits                   \\
%   newpage
%9
Besoin d’amélioration\par
Veille réglementaire et normative\par
Analyse de données et objectifs de la direction\par
Modification interne importante de l’entreprise
    &   Organiser les revues\par
    (processus et de  direction)\par
    (Mesurer et surveiller la performance des\newline processus et de l’organisme)
        &   Revues de direction et Compte-Rendus de revue de direction                               \\
%10
NC, Matériovigilance
    &   Informer le fabricant, les autorités 
        &   CAPA \par 
            Signalement aux autorités
        compétentes ou le client distribué, fiche  de rappel produit
        (si produit déjà)                       \\
%11
Politique et objectifs qualité,\newline Rapports d’audits, Indicateurs\par
Exigences clients
    &   Superviser l’amélioration continue \newline Mettre en place des indicateurs 
        &   Système qualité CAPA\par
            (lié aux actions correctives et préventives)\par
             Indicateurs performants\par
            Modification interne importante (SMQ ou personnel)  \\
%12
Retours d’informations et réclamations\par
Interrogations clients
    &   Analyser les réclamations et répondre aux interrogations clients 
        &   Registres des réclamations, des NC, des rappels et des retraits    \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

You won't see thin white lines in the colored panels, whatever PDF you use.